# BeautifulSoup: 'NoneType' error that raises from time to time

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


tagsnumber = 0
even = 0
descdict_counter = -1
linkdict = {}

w3schools = requests.get('http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp').text
table = bs(w3schools, "lxml").tbody
tdlist = table('td')  # to find the descriptions
alist = table('a')    # to get all the links
for link in alist:
    descdict_counter += 2  # to extract all the even td for decsriptions
    fulllink = str('http://www.w3schools.com/tags/' + link.get('href'))
    shortdesc = str(tdlist[descdict_counter].string)
    key_iter = {str(link.string): fulllink}
    linkdict.update(key_iter)
    tagsnumber += 1
print('Total tags imported: ' + str(tagsnumber))
print(linkdict)
```

Guys, help. I really don't get it. The thing is that I get pretty popular «NoneType» error, but… NOT ALWAYS. Sometimes this code really produces the result. How is it possible? The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    tdlist = table('td')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Also please comment on silly/redundant code, if you can.

Comment: If you are looking for the table of all HTML tags, than it is in `table=bs(w3schools, "lxml").find(class_='w3-table-all')`. Always use `class` or `id` to locate elements, if they are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with what @DYZ said. Beyond that, you might be interested in an alternative to BeautifulSoup that sometimes provides access to simpler solutions via xpath expressions. It's lxml.

```
>>> import requests
>>> w3schools = requests.get('http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp').text
>>> from lxml import html
>>> tree = html.fromstring(w3schools)
>>> links = tree.xpath('//table[@class="w3-table-all notranslate"]//a')
>>> len(links)
119
>>> descrips = tree.xpath('//table[@class="w3-table-all notranslate"]//td[2]')
>>> len(descrips)
119
>>> links[0].attrib
{'href': 'tag_comment.asp'}
>>> descrips[0].text
'Defines a comment'
```

EDIT: Almost forgot: Your code depends on the presence of a tbody tag. Browsers will happily display pages containing tables that lack this tag. Consequently it's often omitted, even today when there's little excuse. But it's absence will make your code croak, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at that lib to parse. But can you answer why the exact code I've shared above sometimes works, but sometimes doesn't? I'm a novice at this point and it doesn't seem right to me to change the library to work with when such a mysterious thing appeared there.

Comment: That's what the edit at the end is about. It can only be a guess because one would have to be able to compare html pages where your code works with html pages where it doesn't. Your code failed when it tried to find a 'tbody' tag. That's why the value of 'table' was None. If this line of code worked previously then that implies that the html had a 'tbody' tag. In other words, it's unsafe to assume the presence of this tag. I agree about changing libraries. However, you also seemed to be asking about how to write neater code. Comment again if this isn't clear.

Comment: I'll try to avoid referring to `<tbody` tag in future, thanks for your comment on it. However, the page I'm trying to parse here actually has such tag in its body, we can see it in source… or… wait a minute. I've tried to reload the page couple of times now and sometimes there's no `<tbody>`. Now I get it, despite of the fact that I have no idea why the site generate different pages on the same request.